# Selenium xpath stored string/vs direct string

Tags: selenium, xpath

Why can I not do the following:

```
String xpathString = "\"(//input[@name='FIN'])" + "[" + 3 + "]\"";
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathString)).click();
```

As I get the following error

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
```

However, the following does not cause an error and works fine

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='FIN'])[3]")).click();
```

The reason I want to use a stored string is that I want to use a loop to loop through the different instances and find the one that doesn't cause an error when clicked.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried logging or setting a breakpoint after setting `xpathString` to see what that value actually is?

Comment: Ah I see, I've been silly and tried to include the quotes in my string, but obviously they were denoting a string in the xpath and are not needed if I'm using a stored string value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, try by simply removing back-Slash following double quotes.
like this,

"(//input[@name='FIN'])["+3+"]"

or to make it dynamic,

"(//input[@name='FIN'])["+i+"]"

Answer (score 0):

remove the quotes from the stored string!